# Изменить заголовок окна в консольном приложении Golang

Tags: golang, cmd

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить заголовок окна в консольном приложении Golang ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Под Windows это можно сделать функцией [SetConsoleTitle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle). Осталось найти пакет для golang с обёрткой для WinApi и вызвать эту функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На картинке - окно терминала, в котором запущен exe-шник.

Заловок такому окну присваивает операционная система.

В комментариях insolor подсказал, что заголовок окна консоли можно поменять с помощью функции WinAPI SetConsoleTitle.

Осталось понять, как из go выызвать winapi - функции.

Я этого никогда не делал, но вот какую заметку удалось нагуглить:

[голанг, вызов функции GetVolumeInformation winapi - winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35238933/4827341)

Надеюсь, это поможет!

Comment: Помню в Python можно так делать в место написаного пити к файлу в заголовке, можно было менять на любое название... И на С++ можно менять с помощью функции System("Название заголовка CMD окна") ... А вот на Go найти не могу :(

Comment: Заголовок окна консоли можно поменять с помощью функции WinAPI SetConsoleTitle (без перебора всех открытых окон, функция меняет именно заголовок окна привязанной к процессу консоли).

Comment: @insolor - Спасибо от нас всех! Может, напишете ответ? мой бесполезнный, я его убираю

Comment: попроовал, вместе с ответом удаляются т комментраии. Если ьудет другой ответ - это можно убрать

Comment: @S.H. я не пишу на go и не в курсе как там использовать функции WinAPI